# How to use d3's each method with ES6 arrow notation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For some reason, d3 uses `this` to refer to the current element in a `.each()` iteration.

I had this code:

```
var me = this;
...
d3.selectAll(".region").each(function(d) {
    d3.select(this).style("fill", me.compute_color(...));
})
```

With ES6, I can use the arrow notation to avoid overwriting `this`:

```
d3.selectAll(".region").each(d => {
    d3.select(this).style("fill", this.compute_color(...));
})
```

However, this code doesn't work because d3 is selecting the wrong element. In fact, I have lost the only reference to the element, because `this` was not overridden by d3.

How can I change `d3.select(this)` so that it works?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think you can't without changing d3.each code, as arrow function doesn't pick the this that is sent by their code (the node). So guess for those cases staying the traditional way is the best

Comment: The issue is that I removed the old `me` from everywhere... I don't want to rollback everything

Comment: Mmm, maybe you could iterate on your own: d3.selectAll(".region")[0].forEach(d => {
 d3.select(d).style("fill", this.compute_color(...));
}) but here d will refer to the d3 element and not the data

Comment: Or make your own eachArrow function using their each code as reference: http://jsfiddle.net/pW4Te/64/

Comment: you can't use a custom `this` on fat arrow, the one in effect at create time is baked in, just like closures...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index that is passed as second argument to access the right element from the collection:

```
let selection = d3.selectAll(".region");
selection.each((d, i) => {
    d3.select(selection[0][i]).style("fill", this.compute_color(...));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
d3.selectAll(".region").each((data, index, nodes) => {
    d3.select(nodes[index]).style("fill", this.compute_color(...));
});
```